# Assume that $T$ is a linear transformation $T: V → ℝ$ and $T(\mathbf{v}_1)=1$ , $T(\mathbf{v}_2)=-1$, find $T(3\mathbf{v}_1-5\mathbf{v}_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume that $T$ is a linear transformation $T: V\to\mathbb{R}$

$T(\mathbf{v}_1)=1$, $T(\mathbf{v}_2)=-1$

find  $T(3\mathbf{v}_1-5\mathbf{v}_2)$

Not sure how to go about this question

Comment: Do you know what it means for a map to be linear?

Comment: T1. T(v + v1)=T(v)+T(v1) for all v and v1 in V 

T2. T(rv)= rT(v) for all v in V and all r in ℝ I just don't understand how to actually prove that one or both don't hold.

Comment: @TaljanaD $T(3\mathbf{v}_1-5\mathbf{v}_2)=3T(\mathbf{v}_1)-5T(\mathbf{v}_2)=\dotsb$

Comment: Is that honestly it you just have to replace the value of **v**1 by 1 and **v**2 by -1?

3(1)-5(-1)=8 

Now I feel like an idiot haha but thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $T$ is a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), we have:

$$T(3v_1-5v_2)=T(3v_1)-T(5v_2)=3T(v_1)-5T(v_2)=3\cdot1-5\cdot-1=3+5=8$$

Comment: Thanks again! and thanks for always fixing my coding, I'm new to this as you can probably tell haha.